# Combining two SQL results into a single table

Tags: mysql

In my mySQL project I need to get a result of 3 columns: *name, items, items_with_condition*. The data are stored in a **single** table (myTable).

It's easy get the result of *name, items*.

```
SELECT name, COUNT(DISTINCT pid) AS items
FROM myTable
GROUP BY name
```

Also easy to get the result for *name, items_with_condition*.

```
SELECT name, COUNT(DISTINCT pid) AS items_with_condition
FROM myTable
WHERE someColumn='something'
GROUP BY name
```

But now I am unable to **combine these two results into one table** with *name, items, items_with_condition* columns using only SQL. Could you please help me? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Select sum(name=...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT 
   name
   , COUNT(DISTINCT pid) AS items
   , COUNT(DISTINCT CASE 
                      WHEN someColumn='something' THEN pid 
                    END) AS items_with_condition
FROM myTable
GROUP BY name
```